# MySQL query using date with python returns always the same ID

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

I'm trying to query a MySQL DB with a date and return an id. My table is as follows:

```
| periodid | period     |
| -------- | ---------- |
| 3        | 2014-04-01 |
| 7        | 2014-09-01 |
| 8        | 2014-07-01 |
| 9        | 2014-02-01 |
```

I can add records to this table using pymysql. But when I try to select the id with where clause, all I can get is 1. Here is the code:

```py
import pymysql
from datetime import datetime

conn = pymysql.connect(user="", password="", host="", database="")
c = conn.cursor()

period = "01-02-2014"
date = datetime.strptime(period, '%d-%m-%Y')
# date returns datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 1, 0, 0)

c.execute("SELECT PeriodID FROM Periods WHERE Period = %s", (date, ))
# returns 1, always 1
```

I even tried as a string "2014-02-01" and also made a string out of date, using the code below:

```py
str_date = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

I still get 1 in return. After 1 hour of trying, I decided to ask. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After executing the cursor.execute you have to fetch the records

Try adding fetchall() at the end and check

For more information check below link

https://thepythonguru.com/fetching-records-using-fetchone-and-fetchmany/

Comment: That's what I needed. Thanks a lot :)